# Node.js remote server not working (Etherpad Lite)

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, http, etherpad

I'm running a server-side application on a remote server, using a particular port - call this port 9000.  Using a separate laptop, I've been able to `telnet` to a simple Java hello world TCP server and to access a HTTP server through my browser.  These listened to port 9000 and were made using the standard Java libraries and `com.sun.net.httpserver`.  However, when I use Node.js to create an application (i.e. `server.listen(9000, 0.0.0.0)`), I cannot connect to that application.

Is there something additional I should do to create a successfully listening HTTP server using Node.js?  Any additional dependencies?  As per above, assume there are no firewall issues between my laptop and my server.

For a larger context, the program I'm trying to run is [etherpad-lite](http://etherpad.org), which uses Node.js to create a server.

Comment: If the server is remote, why are you trying to connect on `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: That is the server-side listening code I'm running, not client-side.  On the client, I connect via the browser (e.g., "http://myservername:9000/").

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the IP address of `0.0.0.0`.

This is telling the server to only listen to requests to that 'hostname'.

Just use

```
server.listen(9000);
```

Comment: Found the solution to my problem; apparently it was some firewall or permissions issue (I thought I got rid of all of those).  Whether I listen using `server.listen(9000);` or `server.listen(9000,0.0.0.0);` doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Nice. That's worth adding as an answer